# Reset filters *and* default sorting with the TableSorter plugin

Tags: jquery, sorting, filter, tablesorter, reset

I'm using the jQuery plugin by Mottie https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/ and have seen the ability to reset filters using an external link. I have seen the same with sorting. However, I want to be able to reset filters **and** restore the default sorting.

This is what I have, which is not working for the sorting, but is at least resetting the filters.

HTML:
`<a href="#" id="reset-link">reset</a>`

JavaScript:

```
$('#reset-link').click(function(){
    $('#mytable').trigger('sortRestart').trigger('filterReset');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Did you mean to call `.trigger('sortReset')`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reverse the order of the triggers ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/1005/))

```
$(function() {
  var $table = $('#mytable');
  $('#reset-link').click(function() {
    $table.trigger('filterReset').trigger('sortReset');
    return false;
  });
  $table.tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    sortList: [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0]],
    widgets: ['filter', 'zebra']
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!